# Pandas rolling apply skip certain values

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, rolling-average

I have a dataframe and I want to calculate the `mean` column up til the value points I have for True valid cases.

```
ids              valid           value      mean (target output)
 1               False            0.1         0
 1               True             0.2        0.2
 1               True             0.4        0.3
 2               True             0.1        0.1
 2               False            0.5        0.1
 2               True             0.3        0.2
 3               True             0.1        0.1
 3               True             0.1        0.1
 3               False            0.5        0.1
 3               False            0.9        0.1
```

How do I exclude the False cases from the mean calculation but still carries on the previous mean. I tried this but it doesn't skip the values from the False cases. I also tried df[~df.valid] before groupby but index doesn't match the original df.

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('ids').value.rolling(len(df), min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x)).values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by writing a customised rolling mean with `groupby.apply`

```
df['mean'] = (
    df
    .groupby('ids')
    .apply(
        lambda df_: (df_['valid'] * df_['value']).cumsum() / (df_['valid']).cumsum()
    )
    .fillna(0)  # No valid rows seen -> 0
    .values     # get rid of the index
)
print(df)

   ids  valid  value  mean (target output)  mean
0    1  False    0.1                   0.0   0.0
1    1   True    0.2                   0.2   0.2
2    1   True    0.4                   0.3   0.3
3    2   True    0.1                   0.1   0.1
4    2  False    0.5                   0.1   0.1
5    2   True    0.3                   0.2   0.2
6    3   True    0.1                   0.1   0.1
7    3   True    0.1                   0.1   0.1
8    3  False    0.5                   0.1   0.1
9    3  False    0.9                   0.1   0.1
```

Since a rolling mean is just the sum divided by the number of observations, we can create rolling versions of both with the `cumsum` while suppressing invalid rows by setting both observation number and value to zero.